# Is there any possibility to change the interval-steps while using Primefaces timeline custom

Tags: primefaces, timeline, vis.js, vis-timeline

Is it somehow possible to set an interval for the event-object (rangechange event)?

This behaviour is shown on their [website/showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/custom.xhtml?jfwid=4555a).

I know that it depends on the zoom level, but I'd like to set the interval to 15min-steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "<p:poll"
here is an example from primefaces website

xhtml:

```
<div class="card">
    <h:form>
        <h1 class="p-text-center">
            <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{pollView.number}"/>
        </h1>

        <p:poll interval="2" listener="#{pollView.increment}" update="txt_count"/>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PollView implements Serializable {

    private int number;

    public void increment() {
        number++;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer,  but i wanted to stick with the Timeline